# R: Shift multiple columns by different number of rows

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a list of tibbles like the following:

```
list(A = structure(list(
                        ID = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), 
                        g1 = c(0, 1, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
                        g2 = c(NA, NA, NA, 3, 4, 5, NA, NA, NA), 
                        g3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6, 7, 8)), 
                   row.names = c(NA, -9L), 
                   class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), 

     B = structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2), 
                        g1 = c(10, 11, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
                        g2 = c(NA, NA, 12,13, NA, NA), 
                        g3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 14, 15)), 
                   row.names = c(NA, -6L), 
                   class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
     )
```

Each element looks like this:

```
  ID    g1    g2    g3
<dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
  1     0    NA    NA
  2     1    NA    NA
  3     2    NA    NA
  1    NA     3    NA
  2    NA     4    NA
  3    NA     5    NA
  1    NA    NA     6
  2    NA    NA     7
  3    NA    NA     8
```

The g* columns are created dynamically, during previous mutates, and their number can vary, but it will be the same across all list elements.

Every g* column has only certain non-NA elements (as many as the unique IDs).

I would like to shift the g* columns so that they contain the non-NA element to the top rows.

I can do it for a single column by

```
num.shifts<- rle(is.na(myList[[1]]$g1))$lengths[1]
shift(myList[[1]]$g2,-num.shifts)
```

but how can I do it for all the g* columns, for all list elements, when I don't know in advance the number of g* columns?

Ideally, I would like a tidyverse solution, but not a requirement...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can loop over the `list` with `map`, and use `mutate_at` to go over the columns that `matches` the 'g' followed by digits and `order` based on the non-NA elements

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
map(lst1, ~ 
       .x %>%
           mutate_at(vars(matches('^g\\d+')), ~ .[order(is.na(.))]))
```

---

In `base R`, we can do

```
lapply(lst1, function(x) {i1 <- grepl("^g\\d+$", names(x))
                     x[i1] <- lapply(x[i1], function(y) y[order(is.na(y))])
                 x})
```

Comment: Excellent! I was focused so much on a `shift` solution, that I missed the `order` alternative!